# which window is on top on the other

Tags: c++, winapi

I have 2 windows and I want to know which window is on the top of the other? 
I tried to test using GetWindowLong and comparing the results but no chance.

```
    LONG wndState1 = ::GetWindowLong(handler1, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    LONG wndState2 = ::GetWindowLong(handler2, GWL_EXSTYLE);
```

both results is equal to 256.

Edited: In the picture below I have the dialog of notepad++ is on top of the FileZilla, How do I Get That by Code.

Is there a trick for that ?

THank you

[image: My Image]

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "on the top of the other"

Comment: for example :  I have the dialog of notepad++ is on top of the FileZilla, How do I Get That by Code.

Comment: This is a prime example of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have to Make something to test after a user click on many windows, I would be able to say which window is above which one ? Let say (window A is under WindowB and B is Under C) ...

Comment: You could enumerate through top level windows in z-order by calling `GetWindow()` with `GW_HWNDFIRST` and `GW_HWNDNEXT` but it's not reliable. From the reference: "_An application that calls GetWindow to perform this task risks being caught in an infinite loop or referencing a handle to a window that has been destroyed._". The reference recommends using `EnumWindows` but there is no documentation about the order in which `EnumWindows` enumerates the windows.

Comment: I think the dangers of GetWindow stem from race conditions (user is actively changing the order or is closing windows).  If you're prepared for those, you can probably cope with them.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: There's no conceivable way to be prepared for handle re-use.

Comment: @IInspectable:  You could set an upper bound:  find an answer after examining _n_ windows or fail.  The fundamental problem is a race condition, so the answer is rather meaningless if windows are coming and going at the moment you're trying to determine the answer.

Answer (score -2):

`GetWindowLong` is used to retrieve style information for a particular window.

In order to get the top-most window, use

```
HWND WINAPI GetForegroundWindow(void);
```

You will still need to know the window handles (HWND) for the processes you're interested in so that you can find out which process owns the foreground window.

Note that this API can only return the window that the user is interacting with (or has interacted with most recently).

UPDATE:

I agree with Remy that there isn't any API to do that. The only way I can think of to actually do that is to install a global hook and intercept certain messages (e.g. WM_ACTIVATE, WM_SETFOCUS and so on). Since you will also retrieve the timestamps for the messages, it should be simple to infer which window is on top of any other window. This will require you to write a dll but this is relatively simple to do. I can't guarantee this will work either though I think it will (I've written a global hook but never used it to find out the z-order of windows)

Comment: The *foreground window* and a window with the *topmost style* aren't necessarily the same. In fact, they rarely are. This answer isn't useful, I'm afraid.

Comment: It also won't tell you if a given non-foreground window is covering another window. There really isn't any API to query z-order information.

Comment: so is there a way to retreve the z-order of windows ?

Comment: @IInspectable, I wasn't sure whether the OP was interested in finding the foreground window or the z-order (I did say that the foreground window is the one the user is interacting with)

Comment: If you aren't sure, leave a comment asking for clarification. Besides, your update fails to account for the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` [extended window style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx).

Comment: Why should it account for WS_EX_TOPMOST? The idea is to obtain a relative z-order position between any two windows and the times of WM_ACTIVATE (and possibly some other messages) should be enough to infer that information. If you query z-order information for windows that haven't been active (receiving activation/focus messages) since a global hook was installed, you obviously won't be able to do much (except to tell they're behind those windows that have received WM_ACTIVATE and WM_SETFOCUS respectively.

Comment: Topmost windows are always in front of non-topmost windows in the Z order. Window activation doesn't change that. Looking at activation messages alone won't allow you to deduce the Z order, when windows with the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` window style are involved.

Comment: Yes, you're right. And there are other restrictions as well with trying to use a global hook to infer Z-order information so this solution is, at best, only partially useful.